# How to define macro containing TikZ \coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I am trying to create a macro to calculate the center of a shape.
Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\getcellcent}[4]{
  \coordinate (#1) at ($1/3*(V#2)+1/3*(V#3)+1/3*V(#4)$);
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (V1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (V2) at (2,0);
    \coordinate (V3) at (1,1);
    \getcellcent{C1}{1}{2}{3}
    \draw[black] (V1) -- (V2) -- (V3) -- cycle;
    \node[circle,radius=1,fill=red] at (C1)  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here I get the following error message:

```
Runaway argument?
1/3*V(3)$);  \draw [black] (V1) -- (V2) -- (V3) -- cycle; \node [circ\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \tikz@cc@parse@factor.
```

If I change the line with \getcellcent to

```
\coordinate (C1) at ($1/3*(V1)+1/3*(V2)+1/3*(V3)$);
```

It works fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: the brace in `V(#4)` is wrong, it should be before the "V".

Comment: I confirm this, it works with `\coordinate (#1) at ($1/3*(V#2)+1/3*(V#3)+1/3*(V#4)$);`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You have the eye of a "hawk". Will you post this as an answer to close the question?

Comment: Thank you! I should of course have spotted this mistake myself..

Comment: You can also do a similar calculation without the `calc` library using `\coordinate (#1) at (barycentric cs:V#2=1/3,V#3=1/3,V#4=1/3);`

Comment: @YiannisLazarides, Stefan, Ulrike: If it is just a typo or similar isn't it better to close it as "too localized"?

Comment: @MartinScharrer Although it was a syntax error, the title was very good and percusse's comment offers an alternative way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the opening brace in `V(#4)` is wrong, it should be before the "V"